# Elasticsearch mapping - Different types of data in same field

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-mapping

I am trying to create a mapping for my Elasticsearch that would make me insert an both an object and a string into my field "value". The following shows the data I want inserted:

```
  {
    "Data": [{
            "key": "keyName",
            "value": "valueName"
        },
        {
            "key": "keyName",
            "value": "valueName"
        },
        {
            "key": "keyName",
            "value": [{
                "type": "FailedName",
                "message": "FailedMessage",
                "path": "FailedPath"
            }]
        }
    ]
  }
```

Would it be possible for me to have two types of data in the same field?
I am running Elasticsearch version 7.3.1.

Comment: If you have control over the messages, it would be easier to just make everything an object and then set the type/path instead of having two separate structures.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. You will have to create two fields, a text field "value" and another nested "value" field (e.g. "value_txt" and "value_nested").

I don't know if your application can model the data to generate these two fields before indexing but if it is not possible you will have to create a script to check if the "value" is a String type, if it is you will set the value in the field " value_txt", otherwise in "value_nested".

Comment: hmm, in case of you dont need to index (= no search) why not just serialise object as a string and store it in value field. Also add a field indicate if you serialise or no the field. Obviously if you need to query this field, you will be in trouble :)

Comment: @LeBigCat Could you elaborate on how I could achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the **object type** 
[https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-types.html#:~:text=object,A%20JSON%20object](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-types.html#:%7E:text=object,A%20JSON%20object).
it should be able to accept both the type
**not sure about the querying part**